# Проблема с кодировкой при работе с СУБД MySQL(Java JDBC)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Здравствуйте при работе с СУБД MySQL возникла проблема с кодировкой русских символов. В базе данных все корректно отображаетсяи и в Java приложении тоже, но когда я пишу запрос UPDATE или INSERT кодировка слетает и кракозябра отображаются как в БД так соответственнно и у меня в приложении... Много уже чего перепробовал, в БД использовал(utf8_general_ci и cp1251_general_ci) для самой БД, таблиц и конкретный полей. При связи с БД также указываю кодировку(также пробовал utf8 и cp1251)

#### jdbc.properties

```
driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestingSystem
user = root
password = admin
charset = utf8
```

#### Database.java

```
private void connect(){
    String urlDB = properties.getProperty("url");
    connectionInfo.put("user", properties.getProperty("user"));
    connectionInfo.put("password", properties.getProperty("password"));
    connectionInfo.put("charSet", properties.getProperty("charset"));
    try {
        Class.forName(properties.getProperty("driver"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        log.error("Not found driver for data base");
    }
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDB, connectionInfo);
        if(connection == null) {
            log.error("Connection with data base isn't open.");
        } else {
            log.info("Connection with data base is open.");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Error connection with data base");
    }
}
```

#### Пример запросов

```
UPDATE basic_data SET data = 'Пример' 
WHERE name = 'Пример'


INSERT INTO test_data_questions(input_data, output_data, id_question) 
VALUES('Пример', 'Пример', (SELECT q.id FROM questions q WHERE q.title = 'Пример'))
```

Может кто-нибудь натолкнет или подскажет в какую сторону стоит копать, потому что сам я уже перепробовал все что мог... Плюс ко всему перед тем как перенес приложение с СУБД Firebird на MySQL вот этот кода работал:

```
public List<TestData> getTestDataForQuestion(String nameQuestion){
    List<TestData> testDataForQuestion = new ArrayList<>();
    String query = "SELECT input_data, output_data " +
                   "FROM test_data_questions " +
                   "WHERE id_question = (SELECT q.id FROM questions q WHERE q.title = '" + nameQuestion + "')";
    ResultSet resultQuery = dataBase.execSelect(query);
    try {
        while(resultQuery.next()){
            String inputData = resultQuery.getString("INPUT_DATA");
            String outputData = resultQuery.getString("OUTPUT_DATA");
            TestData testData = new TestData(inputData, outputData);
            testDataForQuestion.add(testData);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Error is reading test data for Question. Query: " + query);
    }
    return testDataForQuestion;
}
```

А сейчас он просто не находит ниодного поля в таблице, хотя когда захожу через MySQL Workbench и пишу этот же запрос, то работает корретно, вообще не могу понять из-за чего это...

Comment: В запросе INPUT_DATA - маленькими, а в Java большими. Попробуйте найти маленькими, как в запросе Java.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте применить такой URI драйвера JDBC:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestingSystem?characterEncoding=utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

Мучался долго с кодировкой... что-то помогло. Откатил Идею по умолчанию. Дальше:  у меня JDK 19, language level -  18. Все кодировки в проекте поставил по дефолту, в БД стоит кодировка utf8mb3_general_ci. У меня винда 10, кодировка по дефолту в идее ставится на windows-1251. Вдруг поможет кому... цепляю картинки чтобы было понятно о чем тут вообще писал[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]